# Cancel item order Magento 2

Tags: magento2, cancel-orders

I heard that the best practice to cancel an item from an order is to cancel the entire order and create a new one without the canceled item.

Anyone can confirm that and give a hint on how to process this programatically ?

Answer (score 0):

Tiy can Cancel Specific Order Programmatically in this way

```
use Magento\Sales\Api\OrderManagementInterface;

public function __construct(
    OrderManagementInterface $orderManagement
) {
    $this->orderManagement = $orderManagement;
}

public function cacelOrder($orderId)
{
    try {
            $this->orderManagement->cancel(orderId);
            $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage(__('You canceled the order.'));
        } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage($e->getMessage());
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(__('You have not canceled the item.'));
        }
}
```

for reference see `\Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Cancel` in Magneto Core

Comment: Hello, thanks for responding but I'm not sure you've understood my question. I will try to reformulate : How to properly remove an item from an order (not processed yet) ? If you do it in Magento backend, it will cancel the whole order and create a new one without the canceled item. How to do that programmatically ?

Answer (score 0):

A year late but hope this helps someone else:

```
$convertOrderFactory = $this->objectManager->get(\Magento\Sales\Model\Convert\OrderFactory::class);
$convertOrder = $convertOrderFactory->create();
$creditmemo = $convertOrder->toCreditmemo($order);

foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $orderItem) {
    //TODO: Create check for products to cancel

    $qtyShipped = $orderItem->getQtyToShip();
    $creditItem = $convertOrder->itemToCreditmemoItem($orderItem)->setQty($qtyShipped);
    $creditmemo->addItem($creditItem);
}

$creditmemo->setSendEmail(true);
$creditmemo->setCustomerNote('Products out of stock');

$this->creditmemoRepository->save($creditmemo);
```